# C++ for loop nested statements to python

Tags: python, c++, for-loop

How would I translate the following C++ for loop into a python for loop?

```
for(i = xSize - 1; i >= 0 && ptr.points[i] > temp; i--){
    doSomething;
}
```

I am having trouble because of the and operator. Without it, I know it would be like

```
for i in range(xSize - 1, 0, -1)
```

Is this equivalent?

```
for i in range(xSize - 1, 0, -1):
    if ptr.points[i] > temp:
        doSomething
```

Comment: Just break out of the loop once the condition becomes false: `for i in range(xSize-1, 0, -1): if i < 0 or ptr.points[i] <= temp: break else: doSomething`

Comment: thanks, but why use the negation? Does it has advantages?

Comment: They should be equivalent. See the answer I posted (without the negation) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Python itself has no support for this kind of operation.

However, your intuition is right. You can write as you stated, but as @François Andrieux correctly stated, you should also provide a `break` clause.

Also, you should take a look at `itertools` module provided by standard library. It offers a wide rage of functions to deal with efficient looping.

```
from itertools import takewhile, count 
for i in takewhile(lambda i:i > 0 and i<xSize -1 and ptr.Points[i] > temp, i = i-1): doSth()
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python, but it looks to me like the python version of the loop will iterate over all of the range and simply skip those that agree with the predicate. The c++ loop *ends* when the first such value is found, so even if future values don't match it, they will also be "skipped".

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you for the completation, I also completed the answer including your observation

Answer (score 0):

The flow of a C++ for loop is roughly:

```c
for ( initialize; condition; increment/decrement ) {
   doSomething;
}
```

Once the condition evaluates to `false`, execution will break out of the loop. In your example, the condition is `i >= 0 && ptr.points[i] > temp` which means that you will break out of the loop if the value of `i` goes negative or `ptr.points[i] <= temp`.

Thus you can equivalently write:

```c
for(int i = xSize - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(ptr.points[i] > temp) {
        doSomething;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Which, translates quite easily to `python` as:

```
for i in range(xSize-1, 0, -1): 
    if i >= 0 and ptr.points[i] > temp: 
        doSomething
    else:
        break
```

(Though you don't really need the `i >= 0` check)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the python if statement you used or, I believe that is a typo right?

Comment: @paul indeed it was a typo. fixed it. Also note that this is different than what you posted in your question, because your version will not break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be okay as a while loop and intuitive, too, IMHO

```
i=xSize-1
while True:
    if ptr.points[i] > temp:
        doSomething 
    else:
        break
    i-=1
```